# row.split to take comma separated string as one column

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, split

I have two columns - `Wkt` and `LND_STATUS` as a csv file.
I want to insert this into a db as two columns. However, `WKT` column has values with `,`. how do i use row.split(,) but  ignore the `,` in the string `wkt`.

Need to insert complete string as one column.

```
 batch.put_item(Item={
                            'WKT': row.split(',')[0],
                            'LND_STATUS': row.split(',')[1]})

WKT LND_STATUS
MULTIPOLYGON (((103.869724493054 1.36120318421679,103.869710781572 1.36118900486298,103.869697400306 1.36120191041511,103.869690996084 1.36119528058237,103.869648868277 1.36123584376291,103.869637050138 1.36122339265608,103.869642642738 1.36121800704654,103.869623683539 1.36119803361899,103.869618044214 1.36120346437506,103.869581136828 1.36116458537731,103.869611330112 1.36113551055288,103.869618971644 1.3611434190657,103.869643665633 1.36111959860761,103.869608828588 1.36108357288402,103.869583781366 1.36110816661464,103.869590290686 1.36111488948709,103.869548566305 1.36115585882782,103.869657705349 1.36126876523403,103.869724493054 1.3612031821679)))  P LAND
MULTIPOLYGON (((103.88155761112 1.36080286570841,103.881439254321 1.36092432229536,103.881467976679 1.36095308237611,103.881492380399 1.3609283664127,103.881508135246 1.36094412199864,103.881516071228 1.36093608110234,103.88159630643 1.36085448775854,103.881575131181 1.36083298791314,103.88158135 1.36082668979684,103.88155761112 1.36080286570841)))  P LAND
```

`LND_STATUS` should have `P LAND` and `wkt` should have the full string other than `P LAND`.

My input is a csv and use `row.split(,)` to access individual column. I need to 
use `row.split(,)` but to skip the `,` in the first column

Comment: So, in `WKT`, you just want to replace commas`,` with empty string and treat it like a single column?

Comment: `Wkt` has `,` in its string value. I need to keep the `,` as such .. however just insert the entire string as string into a column. but since i am using `row.split(,)`. it is splitting the `,` inside `wkt` column

Comment: i need to use `row.split(,)` - but ignore the `,` in the first column

Comment: there is no `,` in the first column

Comment: `,` is there in the first column - if you cursor through the lines

Comment: You have to be more explicit on what does `row` contains. which part you'd like to put in the `WKT` entry, and which one you'd like to put in `LND_STATUS`

Comment: `LND_STATUS` should have `P LAND` and `wkt` should have the full string other than `P Land`

Comment: It's more clear now, check my answer bellow.

Answer (score 0):

Your CSV is double space separated `'  '`, except for the header. check if it's not just a typo.

```
wkt_, lnd_status_ = row.split('  ')
```

**Edit:** *Parse the `wkt_` part.*

I recommend using a library for this ([`Shapely`](https://pypi.org/project/Shapely/) in this example)

```
import shapely.wkt

row = 'MULTIPOLYGON (((103.869724493054 1.36120318421679,103.869710781572 1.36118900486298,103.869697400306 1.36120191041511,103.869690996084 1.36119528058237,103.869648868277 1.36123584376291,103.869637050138 1.36122339265608,103.869642642738 1.36121800704654,103.869623683539 1.36119803361899,103.869618044214 1.36120346437506,103.869581136828 1.36116458537731,103.869611330112 1.36113551055288,103.869618971644 1.3611434190657,103.869643665633 1.36111959860761,103.869608828588 1.36108357288402,103.869583781366 1.36110816661464,103.869590290686 1.36111488948709,103.869548566305 1.36115585882782,103.869657705349 1.36126876523403,103.869724493054 1.36120318421679)))  P LAND'

wkt_, lnd_status_ = row.split('  ')

multypolygone = shapely.wkt.loads(wkt_)
for polygone in multypolygone:
    for lng, lat in polygone.exterior.coords:
        print((lng, lat))
```

Output

```
(103.869724493054, 1.36120318421679)
(103.869710781572, 1.36118900486298)
(103.869697400306, 1.36120191041511)
(103.869690996084, 1.36119528058237)
(103.869648868277, 1.36123584376291)
(103.869637050138, 1.36122339265608)
(103.869642642738, 1.36121800704654)
(103.869623683539, 1.36119803361899)
(103.869618044214, 1.36120346437506)
(103.869581136828, 1.36116458537731)
(103.869611330112, 1.36113551055288)
(103.869618971644, 1.3611434190657)
(103.869643665633, 1.36111959860761)
(103.869608828588, 1.36108357288402)
(103.869583781366, 1.36110816661464)
(103.869590290686, 1.36111488948709)
(103.869548566305, 1.36115585882782)
(103.869657705349, 1.36126876523403)
(103.869724493054, 1.36120318421679)
```

Comment: My input is a csv and use row.split(,) to access individual column.

Comment: `,` is not actually the separator of the csv, and it seems that you're using the term `column` to point to the components of the multipolygon, which confused me.

I've added some code that parses the multipolygone part.